# Unable to mention people in a comment panel of VSTS on MS Teams

Tags: azure-devops, microsoft-teams, mention

I use VSTS on MS Teams by the following add-in
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsts.vss-services-teams

Thanks to this add-in, I can write comments or change the status of items of VSTS in MS teams window.

However, I can't @mention people in a comment tab.

Please tell me how to do that if it's possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this add-in does not have this functionality yet. Alerts will be sent to team members who are subscribed to changes notifications. An @mention does not trigger such alert.

Comment: Thank you James for so quick answer!
I got it. hope to be implemented soon :(